# Bigquery: Is there a way to round a timestamps UP or DOWN to the NEAREST minute?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, rounding

I've been trying to round UP and DOWN to the NEAREST minute in Bigquery. Does anyone know the best function and method to achieve this?

```
user_id     |  created_at
-------------------------------------
14451       | 2019-01-31 04:51:28 UTC
14452       | 2019-01-31 04:51:31 UTC
14453       | 2019-01-31 04:51:59 UTC
14454       | 2019-01-31 04:51:03 UTC
```

My desired outcome would be the following

```
user_id     |  created_at
-------------------------------------
14451       | 2019-01-31 04:51:00 UTC
14452       | 2019-01-31 04:52:00 UTC
14453       | 2019-01-31 04:52:00 UTC
14454       | 2019-01-31 04:51:00 UTC
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 30 SECOND), MINUTE) created_at
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with this using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 14451 user_id, TIMESTAMP '2019-01-31 04:51:28 UTC' created_at UNION ALL
  SELECT 14452, '2019-01-31 04:51:31 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14453, '2019-01-31 04:51:59 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 14454, '2019-01-31 04:51:03 UTC' 
)
SELECT user_id, 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 30 SECOND), MINUTE) created_at
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row user_id created_at   
1   14451   2019-01-31 04:51:00 UTC  
2   14452   2019-01-31 04:52:00 UTC  
3   14453   2019-01-31 04:52:00 UTC  
4   14454   2019-01-31 04:51:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adds half of the 60 (value of 30) before doing the DIV

```
SELECT user_id ,SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(created_at)+30) DIV 60) * 60) FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

To round down (floor), you can use `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC` (or `DATETIME_TRUNC`) as mentioned, as truncate ["is always rounded to the beginning of date_time_part"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions).  Adding half of a `date_time_part` will help you round to the nearest time, but it won't necessarily round up.

To round up (ceiling) to the nearest minute, you can use this solution:

```
TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(
  TIMESTAMP_ADD(MAX(created_at), INTERVAL 59 SECOND),
  MINUTE
)
```